# how can i match a mySQL row with a specific md5 value? SELECT * FROM TABLE where BINARY MD5='<specific MD5 values>';

Tags: mysql, md5, md5sum

We have a MD5 column:

```
`MD5` BINARY(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

If we do:

```
SELECT MD5 FROM table;
```

returns

[image]

First question: if I go ahead copy and paste that displayed MD5 value somewhere else, I will get the following without the leading "0x". May I know why the displayed and actual copied and pasted MD5 values are different?

```
CFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA
```

second question: how can i select a specific MD5 value in mySQL using WHERE clause?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where BINARY MD5=UPPER('CFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA');

SELECT * FROM TABLE where BINARY MD5='0xCFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA';

SELECT * FROM TABLE where        MD5=UPPER('CFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA');

SELECT * FROM TABLE where        MD5='0xCFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA';
```

All of the above returns nothing.  Could any guru enlighten? Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what you are doing with hashed values in the first place?  A typical use of `MD5` would be to encrypt a user password.  And a typical query would be to compare `MD5(some_password)` against your `MD5` column.  In other words, it is possible that you don't even need to work with hashed values.

Comment: The API will send me a specific MD5 value for each group of data (several rows) to determine whether these rows have been calculated already.  If the API sends me a specific MD5 value, for example, "CFCD208495D565EF66E7DFF9F98764DA", then I will do some special treatment for those rows.

Comment: You should update your question with the exact version of MySQL you are using.  There have been some recent changes to the behavior of `MD5`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 'S FIRST  comment is right on the money, why are you doing it? some special treatment sounds a little 'Free Willy' to me. Check out sqlfiddle with 3 rows (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2721/2/0). Here you see I insert some data, but the `displayed data` differs from the `actual stored data` (hashed), even then I can find it using a simple query (if provided the correct unhashed value)

Comment: Thanks @davejal! It works in sqlfiddle.  However, I don't know why I just cannot reproduce it in my local MySQL 5.6.34.

Comment: Keep in mind, the values you provided are 32 in lenght, not 16. So at the creation, I had to change `MD5 BINARY(16)` to `MD5 BINARY(32)`

Comment: Yeah I also figure this out! BINARY(32)!! Would you like to post an answer and I will give you the credit?!